# No logro obtener el resultado al medir 2 distancia con la api de geolocation

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de obtener la distancia entre dos ubicaciones pero no logro hacerlo funcionar porque me da error.

No sé si es porque estoy pasando la información del input sin hacerle otro proceso o que...

Si decido poner las coordenadas directamente si funciona, ya intenté con parseFloat etc... y no logro obtener la distancia

```js
let user_location = {
latitude: "19.4737327",
longitude: "-99.1922314"
}

// DE ESTE MODO DA ERROR NaN o Undefined
let distance_place = calc(user_location.latitude,user_location.longitude,document.querySelector(".input").value);

console.log(distance_place);

// SI LO PONGO DIRECTAMENTE SI FUNCIONA
let distance_place2 = calc(user_location.latitude,user_location.longitude,19.4860404,-99.1894600);

console.log(distance_place2);


function calc(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    
    let R = 6371;
    let dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    let dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
    let lat10 = toRad(lat1);
    let lat20 = toRad(lat2);

    let a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat10) * Math.cos(lat20); 
    let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    let d = R * c;

    return Math.trunc(d);

}
  
function toRad(Value) {
    
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;

}
```

```html
<input class="input" value="19.4860404,-99.1894600">
```

Comment: Qué error da? Puedes [edit] la pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo NaN o también undefined... pero si pongo las coordenadas que están en el input directamente en la función que se encuentra dentro de distance_place funciona bien

Comment: Para debuggear correctamente, tienes la chance de colocar console.logs por todo lado para ver qué variable está tirando el problema, la otra opción es utilizar las developers tools (F12) y darle al modo `debugger`. El problema que tienes está apuntando a cómo manejas el valor del input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingresas el input cuyo valor es "19.4860404,-99.1894600", esto no es número. Debes separarlo por la "," (hacer un split(,)) y transformarlo a número

```js
let user_location = {
latitude: "19.4737327",
longitude: "-99.1922314"
}

let distance_place = calc(
user_location.latitude,
user_location.longitude,
document.querySelector(".input").value);


console.log(distance_place);


function calc(lat1, lon1, input) {
    input = input.split(",");
    let lat2 = Number(input[0].trim());
    let lon2 = Number(input[1].trim());
    let R = 6371;
    let dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    let dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1);
    let lat10 = toRad(lat1);
    let lat20 = toRad(lat2);

    let a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat10) * Math.cos(lat20); 
    let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    let d = R * c;

    return Math.trunc(d);

}
  
function toRad(Value) {
    
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;

}
```

```html
<input class="input" value="19.4860404,-99.1894600">
```